# Regex Split String at particular word pattern different different value

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, oracle

I am doing dynamic reporting system. For Front End i using Asp.net and oracle as Back End. Project requirement is that, user can write query in a TextBox and when click on button from the Query after **WHERE** keyword all parameters where split. Split will work on according to pattern, when (**AND** | **OR** | **,** ) will find on Query.

For Example:-

```
select * from EmpInfo where age >= 40, active='A' and rownum < 15
```

result will

```
age >= 40
active='A'
rownum < 15
```

But if i use subquery after where then also same pattern will follow

For Example:-

```
select * from EmpInfo where age in (select age from Emp_pns where age >= 60 ), active='A' and rownum < 15
```

result will

```
age >= 60
active='A'
rownum < 15
```

This is my sample code, I try my best but i didn't get perfect solution.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim query As String = TextBox1.Text.ToLower
getParameter(query)
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.Items(i).Text)
Next
End Sub

Public Sub getParameter(ByVal argument As String)
Dim query As String = argument
Static Dim tempString As String
If query.Contains("order by") Or query.Contains("group by") Then
    Dim mtch As Match = Regex.Match(query, "(?<=where)(.*)(?=order by|group by)")
    Dim mtchString As String = mtch.Groups(1).Value
    tempString = mtchString
    If mtchString.Length >= 1 Then
        Dim bindlist As String() = Regex.Split(mtchString, " and | or |,")
        ListBox1.DataSource = bindlist
        ListBox1.DataBind()
         getParameter(tempString)
    End If
Else
    Dim mtch As Match = Regex.Match(query, "(?<=where)(.*)")
    Dim mtchString As String = mtch.Groups(1).Value
    Dim bindlist As String() = Regex.Split(s, " and | or |,")
    ListBox2.DataSource = bindlist
    ListBox2.DataBind()
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, take a look at my code and understand the intrinsic complexity of having to deal with brackets. You cannot rely on split/regex with a so complex reality; or the resulting pattern would be so complicated/inflexible that it wouldn't be worthy. The proposed approach delivers the perfect solution for your situation and even more complex ones. I hope that you haven't misunderstood my statements, I will update my answer now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex` or `Split` deliver accurate performance for clearly defined patterns; the pattern you are looking for is too complex for those methods (the required implementation would be too difficult and, in any case, too rigid). This kind of complex problems should be solved by relying on string analysis. Sample code delivering the expected result with your input string (or equivalent ones):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim inputString As String = "select * from EmpInfo where age in (select age from Emp_pns where age >= 60 ), active='A' and rownum < 15"

        Dim whereString As String = inputString.Substring(inputString.ToLower().IndexOf("where") + "where".Length, inputString.Length - (inputString.ToLower().IndexOf("where") + "where".Length)).Trim()
        Dim allParts(whereString.Length + 2) As String
        Dim allPartsCount As Integer = 0
        Dim done As Boolean = False
        If (whereString.Contains("(") And whereString.Contains(")")) Then
            If (whereString.Split("(").Length = whereString.Split(")").Length) Then
                done = True
                Dim remString = whereString
                Do
                    Dim temp = inBrackets(remString)
                    If (temp(0).Trim().Length > 0) Then
                        allPartsCount = allPartsCount + 1
                        allParts(allPartsCount) = temp(0)
                    End If
                    If (temp(1).Trim().Length > 0) Then
                        remString = temp(1)

                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop While (remString.Trim().Length > 0)
            End If
        End If
        If (Not done) Then
            'Standard treatment
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function inBrackets(inputString As String) As String()

        Dim outStrings(1) As String

        Dim openBracket As Boolean = False
        Dim count As Integer = -1
        Do
            count = count + 1
            outStrings(0) = outStrings(0) & inputString.Substring(count, 1)
            If (inputString.Substring(count, 1) = "(") Then
                openBracket = Not openBracket
            ElseIf (openBracket And inputString.Substring(count, 1) = ")") Then
                openBracket = False
            End If

            If (Not openBracket) Then
                If (inputString.Substring(count, 1) = ",") Then
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf (count >= "and".Length AndAlso inputString.ToLower().Substring(count - "and".Length, "and".Length) = "and") Then
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf (count >= "or".Length AndAlso inputString.ToLower().Substring(count - "or".Length, "or".Length) = "or") Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop While (count < inputString.Length - 1)

        If (outStrings(0).Trim().Length > 0) Then
            outStrings(1) = inputString.Substring(outStrings(0).Length, inputString.Length - outStrings(0).Length)
        End If

        Return outStrings

    End Function
End Class
```

This code shows a typical approach to this kind of situations: you are expected to adapt/extend it as much as required to fulfill your exact requirements. It analyses cases just having brackets (parallel number of opening/closing brackets). The idea is pretty simple: analyses the given string character by character until finding one of the "separators" you are looking for, with an additional consideration: in case of finding an opening bracket, it would not exit the loop until finding the corresponding closing one. The function performing the analysis returns an array with the current bit and the remaining string such that the main loop can continue the analysis. Further extensions you should do in any case: accounting for bracket variations (e.g., square brackets), accounting for nested brackets (this code only accounts for "one level of brackets"), etc.

Comment: why these two are different :(... `"this is me".split(/\s/);` vs `"this is me".split(/(\s)/);`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer This is not how split is supossed to be used; also bear in mind that special characters have to be scaped. In any case, I don't think that this has any relationship with your original question and thus you should post a new question. If it is a more or less long/complex issue, you should post a new question. If it is just a simple problem, I can answer it for you (last time, because, as said, this is not how things are supposed to be done): explain the exact input string and how you want to split it.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer ?! You are not the OP?! Why are you asking a so unrelated question with the problem here and with my answer?!

Comment: no i am just trying to understand why its acting different. I am asking cause you seem to know it.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I do know how split behave and how to deal with strings and you are doing both things wrongly. Please, explain what you want and I will write a proper code; what you wrote is non-sense: this code does not compile (you have to surround the splitting character(s) with "" or '' depending upon the fact of being char or string), you have to include splitting character(s) present in the string to split (what is not the case here); if you have special characters you have to scape them (this is a generally-valid rule while dealing with strings/characters).

Comment: @MuhammadUmer and please explain me why you have decided to ask via comment in a question you didn't write (and completely unrelated with your request), to a guy you don't even know... instead of creating a new question.

Comment: are you sure you can see it correctly...i just ran it in console and it works. Here for this example i am escaping space character. the one without brackets works fine but different when `\s` is surrounded with brackets it shows extra spaces in array. It seems to be behavior related to split function. `.match` works fined both way.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer PS: because I guess that you know that this is VB.NET and your question should be VB.NET-related; apparently it is Javascript. I am every second more confused.

Comment: it's ok ill keep on researching.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I am pretty sure how VB.NET works (and, in general, .NET) and I know that this code does not compile. It is clearly not VB.NET; sounds a bit like C#.NET but with the missing quotes and the wrong caps. By looking at your profile, you seem to know Javascript and this can be Javascript.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I recommend you to think a bit before continue your search: what is split for? For splitting. You want to split this string based on what? On "s"; then, why are you putting all the /\ stuff? What is the exact point. You want to split it based on "s" (not sure about the reason)? Remove all the slashes; you want to bring slashes into account? Then replace the string to split because "this is me" does not contain any slash. Just think twice about your problem and you will surely come to a solution. Also, please, in the future intend to use this site properly :)

Comment: relax this is js in it it's perfect way.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I thought so (I am very relaxed). Summary: you are asking via comment, to a person you don't know, in a question you didn't write, something completely unrelated to the question/answer and, on top of everything, about a different language (on which, the person you are asking to does not have too much experience, as you can see on his profile) -> how can I not be relaxed with such a situation? This is the kind of thing which only can bring a smile to my face :)

Comment: omg...all you had to do is say i don't know js. I can't help you. If this is js. No speeches plz. Good day

Comment: @MuhammadUmer don't take it badly. You have to agree with me: it has been certainly peculiar. I do know Javascript (although I am not an expert); additionally the basic functions (like Split) work more or less similarly in all the languages. Also it is pretty clear that there is no relationship between the string to split and the splitting characters (which is something quite important). I recommend you to analyse calmly what you want to accomplish and will find the way through without any problem.

Comment: \s stands for white space characters.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Lesson learned. But what stand "(" and ")" for?